# Expanding functions in their taylor series using l'Hopitals

Tags: calculus

Suppose f and g have Taylor Series about the point a.

a. If $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ and $g'(a) \neq 0$, evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to a}$ $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ by expanding f and g in their Taylor series. Show that the result is consistent with l'Hopital's Rule.

b. If $f(a) = g(a) = f'(a) = g'(a) = 0$ and $g''(a) \neq 0$, evalutate $\lim \limits_{x \to a}$ $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ by expanding f and g in their Taylor series. Show that the result is consistent with two applications of l'Hopital's Rule.

My issue does not lie with expanding Taylor polynomials, I'm fine with that. My problem with this particular question is that I'm not even sure what I have to expand. Once I know what to expand, it's simply a matter of expanding it as a Taylor polynomial then taking the derivative of each. Is the hint supposed to be ($f(a) = g(a) = 0$) and such? Any kind of guidance on how to proceed with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expand $f$ and $g$ about around $a$ using the Taylor series. You'll get terms of the form $(a-x) f'(a) + \dots$, as $f(a) = g(a) = 0$. Since $g'(a) \neq 0$, conclude that the limit is equal to $\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$. This is precisely what l'Hopital's rule says. Now try doing the same for the second part (btw, are you sure the condition $g'''(a) \neq 0$ is correct. I believe it should be $g''(a) \neq 0$).

Comment: Just fixed that error, my mistake. So you're saying it's a matter of expanding f(a) over g(a) using Taylor series, then taking the derivative of each? (l'Hopital's Rule). The form that they would take through the Taylor polynomial would be $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac {f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2$. g(a) would look the same, just with g of course.

Comment: Yes, but now, we have polynomials for which we know how they behave close to $a$.!

Comment: Ok excellent, so would the second part mean I would use l'Hopitals rule once more? So technically it would be the second derivative of $f(a)$ over $g(a)$

Comment: No. Just look at the terms which are zero. No need to use L'Hospital.